# Verilog Synchronous state machine

Tags: verilog, state, fsm

I'm trying to design this state machine in verilog:

[image]

I was have:

```
   `timescale 1ns/1ns
module labEightMachine(y, x,clk,clr)
        output      y;
        input [1:2] x;
        input       clk, clr;
        reg [1:2]   q;
        reg         y;
        reg         nX;
        always @ (posedge clk)
            begin
            if(clr)
                {q}<=2'b00;

            else
                q<= {nX}
            end
        always @(y,x)
        begin
        if(q==2'b00)
            if(x==2'b00)
                q<=2'b00;
            else
                q<=2'b01;
                y<=1;
        if(q==2'b01)
            if((x==2'b00)||(x==2'b01))
                q<=2'b00;
                y<=0;
            else
                q<=2'b11;
                y<=0;
        if(q==2'b11)
            if(x==2'b10)
                q<=2'b10;
                y<=1;
            else
                q<=2'b00;
                y<=0;
        if(q==2'b10)
            q<=2'b00;
                y<=0;
        end
endmodule
```

If any one could help by telling me where it is incorrect, that would be greatly appreciated. The state machines confuse me and I'm not sure that I am reassigning everything correctly.

Comment: For easier to understand FSM use a case statements, [asic-world](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/verilog_fsm.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Applying stimulus is always a better way to check your code. Leaving the syntax errors of semi-colons/begin-end and all that, a couple of immediate logical errors I can see are as below.

The declaration `reg nX` declares a variable of **single bit** width. On the contrary, `q` is declared as `reg [1:2] q`, of **two bits** width.

Secondly,`q` is **driven from two always blocks**. If `clr` is LOW, then `q` is driven by `nX`. While, `nX` is never driven by any signal. So, the output will be `x` majority of times (leaving those race-conditions). Multiple driver issues.

Thirdly, it would be better to use `if--else if--else` ladder instead of multiple `if`s. This will make the **next_state logic clear**.

A better FSM, might have two `always` blocks and one output logic block. One for sequential logic and other for combinational logic. Sequential block is used to update the current_state value by the next_state value. While, a combinational block is used to update the next state value according to inputs. The output logic must either have a separate block of continuous assignments or a procedural block.

Also, it might be convenient to use a `case` statement for next_state logic. This will be useful when too many states are interacting with each other in a single FSM. Using `default` in case statement is inevitable.

For further information on efficient FSM coding styles, refer to [CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM.pdf) paper and [CummingsSNUG2000Boston_FSM](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece353/verilog/v_fsm-coding.pdf) paper.